# Passing errors from Lambda to API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am trying to create an "error handler" in API Gateway so that if the lambda function returns a statusCode - 400 for example it will give out on Postman a 400 error.

Currently my lambda function is like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        
        raise ValueError("This is a sample error")
    
    except Exception as e:
        
        return {
            
            'error_description': format_error_info(event, context, e)
        }
        
def format_error_info(event, context, error):
    
    correlation_id = context.aws_request_id
    stage = event.get('stage', 'N/A')
    status_code = 400
    timestamp = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    stack_trace = traceback.format_exc()
    
    error_info = {
        'correlationId' : correlation_id,
        'stage' : stage,
        'status' : status_code,
        'timestamp' : timestamp,
        'errorMessage' : str(error),
        'stackTrace' : stack_trace
    }
    
    return error_info
```

Giving me this response :

```
    "error_description": {
        "correlationId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "stage": "Test_Stage",
        "status": 400,
        "timestamp": "2023-12-20T14:45:09.850502",
        "errorMessage": "This is a sample error",
        "stackTrace": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    raise ValueError(\"This is a sample error\")\nValueError: This is a sample error\n"
    }
}
```

I added into the Method Response a response with a response body Empty(don't mind being 408 it is not important what value is at the moment):

[image]

And finally **what i believe im doing wrong but dont know where** the Integration Response:

[image]

I believe i am doing the **mapping template** or the **regex** wrong. But i dont know how to solve it.